# How do I implement a simple selection menu in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to offer a choice in the console:
*1) Sword
2) Onion*
and if the user enters an incorrect value in cin, then ask them to enter it again

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did not work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int choose()
{
  string choice;
  cout<<"1) Sword\t2) Onion\n";
  cin>>choice;
  while (choice != "1" && choice!="2") {//<-- looping here until we get a valid input
    cout<<"Invalid choice! (must  be 1 or 2)\nTry again:\n";
    cin>>choice;
  }
  return stoi(choice);

}
```

Comment: @QuentinUK True, but then you have to deal with `cin`-errors if the user-input doesn't conver to an `int`.